# How can i create a pdf file and then stored it into sharepoint library without using local machine?

Tags: pdf, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Below is the code what i have written till now. Its creating a file and also file gets added into document library but it wont content any content. Is it possible to do so ? or any other way to implement it?

```
            FileStream fileStream = System.IO.File.Create("dfd.pdf");
            string input = "Dot Net Perls";

            // Invoke GetBytes method.
            // ... You can store this array as a field!
            byte[] array = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);

            //string input = fileStream.ToString();
            //
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("BankDoc");
            FileCreationInformation f = new FileCreationInformation();
            fileStream.Write(array,0,array.Length);
            //f.ContentStream = fileStream as Stream;
            byte[] contents = new byte[fileStream.Length];
            f.Url = "tejaaaasjjjj.pdf";
            f.Content = contents;
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = list.RootFolder.Files.Add(f);
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection itemcol = list.GetItems(new CamlQuery());
            uploadFile.ListItemAllFields["Title"] = "TEJASSSSSS";

            uploadFile.ListItemAllFields.Update();
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a third party library like [PDFSharp](http://pdfsharp.codeplex.com/releases/view/37054) to generate your PDF file.

Answer (score 0):

There are many third party library like Aspose to resolve it. or you will try other products which convert files to PDF files and also get adds files to local document library, like [PDF converter](http://www.boostsolutions.com/sharepoint-pdf-converter.html).